# How to add shadow to reverse c radial gradient only at the edges?

Tags: css, shadow, css-shapes, radial-gradients

I am new to this topic and have not found anywhere how to apply shadow to the reverse C type corners only.

Below is the link of Example image for which I am trying to add shadow only to the corners

[image]

Below is the code which I have used to achieve this reverse rounded corner:

CSS Code:

```css
div {
  background-color: #a9a8a8;
  background: -moz-radial-gradient(0 100%, circle, rgba(204, 0, 0, 0) 100px, #f7f6f6 15px), -moz-radial-gradient(100% 100%, circle, rgba(204, 0, 0, 0) 100px, #f7f6f6 15px), -moz-radial-gradient(100% 0, circle, rgba(204, 0, 0, 0) 100px, #f7f6f6 15px), -moz-radial-gradient(0 0, circle, rgba(204, 0, 0, 0) 100px, #f7f6f6 15px);
  background: -o-radial-gradient(0 100%, circle, rgba(204, 0, 0, 0) 100px, #f7f6f6 15px), -o-radial-gradient(100% 100%, circle, rgba(204, 0, 0, 0) 100px, #f7f6f6 15px), -o-radial-gradient(100% 0, circle, rgba(204, 0, 0, 0) 100px, #f7f6f6 15px), -o-radial-gradient(0 0, circle, rgba(204, 0, 0, 0) 100px, #f7f6f6 15px);
  background: -webkit-radial-gradient(0 100%, circle, rgba(204, 0, 0, 0) 100px, #f7f6f6 15px), -webkit-radial-gradient(100% 100%, circle, rgba(204, 0, 0, 0) 100px, #f7f6f6 15px), -webkit-radial-gradient(100% 0, circle, rgba(204, 0, 0, 0) 100px, #f7f6f6 15px), -webkit-radial-gradient(0 0, circle, rgba(204, 0, 0, 0) 100px, #f7f6f6 15px);
  background-position: bottom left, bottom right, top right, top left;
  -moz-background-size: 50% 50%;
  -webkit-background-size: 50% 50%;
  background-size: 50% 50%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: 300px;
  width: 500px;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

So now I want to **add shadow effect only to the rounded corners** of the dark grey section. I want to illustrate the effect like the light grey is come on top of the grey.

Comment: Could you add some HTML in your snippet so it does indeed illustrate your problem?

Comment: Sorry, wrongly closed seeing the shape and so re-opened.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you are already using a `radial-gradient` to create the border corner scoop shape, all that is needed is to add an extra color-stop position in between to produce the shadow effect.

In the below snippet, we use the following gradient (for each corner):

```
radial-gradient(circle at 0 100%, rgba(204, 0, 0, 0) 100px, #AAA 104px, #f7f6f6 105px)
```

This gradient can be interpreted as follows:

- The color of the radial gradient is `rgba(204, 0, 0, 0)` upto `100px` radius from the center of the circle. The color is a transparent color and produces the effect of a reverse C cut (or a scoop).
- From the `100px` radius to `104px` radius, the color gradually changes from `rgba(204, 0, 0, 0)` to `#AAA` (greyish color) and this produces a shadow like effect. You can change the color of the shadow by changing this color value.
- Between `104px` and `105px` radius, color of the gradient changes from `#AAA` to `#f7f6f6` which makes it look the color is changing smoothly instead of a hard-stop.

```css
div {
  background: -moz-radial-gradient(0 100%, circle, rgba(204, 0, 0, 0) 100px, #AAA 104px, #f7f6f6 105px), -moz-radial-gradient(100% 100%, circle, rgba(204, 0, 0, 0) 100px, #AAA 104px, #f7f6f6 105px), -moz-radial-gradient(100% 0, circle, rgba(204, 0, 0, 0) 100px, #AAA 104px, #f7f6f6 105px), -moz-radial-gradient(0 0, circle, rgba(204, 0, 0, 0) 100px, #AAA 104px, #f7f6f6 105px);
  background: -webkit-radial-gradient(0 100%, circle, rgba(204, 0, 0, 0) 100px, #AAA 104px, #f7f6f6 105px), -webkit-radial-gradient(100% 100%, circle, rgba(204, 0, 0, 0) 100px, #AAA 104px, #f7f6f6 105px), -webkit-radial-gradient(100% 0, circle, rgba(204, 0, 0, 0) 100px, #AAA 104px, #f7f6f6 105px), -webkit-radial-gradient(0 0, circle, rgba(204, 0, 0, 0) 100px, #AAA 104px, #f7f6f6 105px);
  background: radial-gradient(circle at 0 100%, rgba(204, 0, 0, 0) 100px, #AAA 104px, #f7f6f6 105px), radial-gradient(circle at 100% 100%, rgba(204, 0, 0, 0) 100px, #AAA 104px, #f7f6f6 105px), radial-gradient(circle at 100% 0, rgba(204, 0, 0, 0) 100px, #AAA 104px, #f7f6f6 105px), radial-gradient(circle at 0 0, rgba(204, 0, 0, 0) 100px, #AAA 104px, #f7f6f6 105px);
  background-position: bottom left, bottom right, top right, top left;
  background-size: 50% 50%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: 300px;
  width: 500px;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

---

If you want to produce an output like in the image provided in comments, have a look at the below snippet. The working of this snippet is the same as the one explained above:

```css
div {
  background: -moz-radial-gradient(0 100%, circle, rgb(168, 168, 168) 100px, rgb(139, 139, 139) 102px, rgb(139, 139, 139) 106px, rgb(246, 246, 246) 106px), -moz-radial-gradient(100% 100%, circle, rgb(168, 168, 168) 100px, rgb(139, 139, 139) 102px, rgb(139, 139, 139) 106px, rgb(246, 246, 246) 106px), -moz-radial-gradient(100% 0, circle, rgb(168, 168, 168) 100px, rgb(139, 139, 139) 102px, rgb(139, 139, 139) 106px, rgb(246, 246, 246) 106px), -moz-radial-gradient(0 0, circle, rgb(168, 168, 168) 100px, rgb(139, 139, 139) 102px, rgb(139, 139, 139) 106px, rgb(246, 246, 246) 106px);
  background: -webkit-radial-gradient(0 100%, circle, rgb(168, 168, 168) 100px, rgb(139, 139, 139) 102px, rgb(139, 139, 139) 106px, rgb(246, 246, 246) 106px), -webkit-radial-gradient(100% 100%, circle, rgb(168, 168, 168) 100px, rgb(139, 139, 139) 102px, rgb(139, 139, 139) 106px, rgb(246, 246, 246) 106px), -webkit-radial-gradient(100% 0, circle, rgb(168, 168, 168) 100px, rgb(139, 139, 139) 102px, rgb(139, 139, 139) 106px, rgb(246, 246, 246) 106px), -webkit-radial-gradient(0 0, circle, rgb(168, 168, 168) 100px, rgb(139, 139, 139) 102px, rgb(139, 139, 139) 106px, rgb(246, 246, 246) 106px);
  background: radial-gradient(circle at 0 100%, rgb(168, 168, 168) 100px, rgb(139, 139, 139) 102px, rgb(139, 139, 139) 106px, rgb(246, 246, 246) 106px), radial-gradient(circle at 100% 100%, rgb(168, 168, 168) 100px, rgb(139, 139, 139) 102px, rgb(139, 139, 139) 106px, rgb(246, 246, 246) 106px), radial-gradient(circle at 100% 0, rgb(168, 168, 168) 100px, rgb(139, 139, 139) 102px, rgb(139, 139, 139) 106px, rgb(246, 246, 246) 106px), radial-gradient(circle at 0 0, rgb(168, 168, 168) 100px, rgb(139, 139, 139) 102px, rgb(139, 139, 139) 106px, rgb(246, 246, 246) 106px);
  background-position: bottom left, bottom right, top right, top left;
  background-size: 50% 50%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: 300px;
  width: 600px;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: Thanks Harry, Very close to what I want, only thing is is we need to get the shadow more better.

http://s17.postimg.org/k9jxodm4v/Screen_Shot_2015_08_27_at_12_46_28_pm.png check this image after implementing the code.

Comment: @ShirishSC: That is reasonably simplet and requires only a small tweak. Refer to the second snippet in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to use 4 corner elements.
All positioned absolute to there relative container.
And with a `box-shadow: 0px 0px |amount-of-blur|length-of-shaodw| color`
I choose to go with `box-shadow: 0px 0px 60px 50px black`

```css
body {
  background-color: #222;
}
.corner-shadow {
  position: relative;
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: white;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.corner-shadow .corner {
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 2px;
  height: 2px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 60px 50px black;
}
.corner.top {
  top: -2px;
}
.corner.left {
  left: -2px;
}
.corner.right {
  right: -2px;
}
.corner.bottom {
  bottom: -2px;
}
```

```html
<div class="corner-shadow">
  <div class="corner top left"></div>
  <div class="corner top right"></div>
  <div class="corner bottom left"></div>
  <div class="corner bottom right"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I want to achieve with only one div as I want to integrate in Visual Builder of my WordPress website. I think the first solution works for me.